# Smoother fixed float

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, positioning

I have created a spirit level for [my new site](http://adamlynch.ie).

I used the [fixed float](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/creating-a-floating-html-menu-using-jquery-and-css/) idea but tried to limit it to the realm of the tube. It's not perfect but it's aided by the shortness of the page.

## How could I make it smoother (particularly when scrolling slowly)?

Also, when I scroll with my iPhone, it works but only after I *finish* scrolling and not *as* I'm scrolling. Is this just a limitation of the iPhone's scrolling mechanism or is there a way around that?

---

#### The [HTML](http://adamlynch.ie):

```
<div id="spirit_level"> 
    <div id="shimmery"></div> <!-- just for y gradient -->
    <div id="shimmerx"></div> <!-- just for x gradient -->
    <div id="bumps"></div> <!-- just for another overlay -->

    <div id="tube"> 
        <div id="bubble"></div> 
        <div id="overside"></div> <!-- glass + line markings -->
    </div>
</div>
<div id="spirit_shadow"></div>
```

#### The [CSS](http://adamlynch.ie/styles/main.css):

The spirit level is placed using fixed positioning, and everything inside is positioned absolutely (relative to the spirit level).

#### The [Javascript](http://adamlynch.ie/js/home.js):

```
/* START: init spirit_level/bubble */
var bubble_h = 53, tube_h = 242, 
doc_h = parseInt($(document).height()),
viewport_h = parseInt($(window).height()),
scrollDepth = $(document).scrollTop(),
orig_scrollDepth = scrollDepth,
tube_top = viewport_h/2 - tube_h/2,
center = 0;

/*center the tube and bubble:
$('#tube').css('top', tube_top+'px')
    .addClass('bubble_prep');

placeBubble(1);
/* END: init spirit_level/bubble */

$(window).unbind("scroll").scroll(function () {
    placeBubble(0);
})
```

The `placeBubble()` function:

```
function placeBubble(first_time)
{
    scrollDepth = $(document).scrollTop();
    if(first_time)
    {
        $('#bubble').css('top', center + 'px');                     
    }

    temp = ((center - (scrollDepth - orig_scrollDepth))/viewport_h)*100;

    $('#bubble').css('top', (temp<-50?-50:(temp>50?50:temp)) +'%')
        .animate(
            {top: (center/viewport_h)*100+'%'},
            {duration:800,queue:false},
            {
                step: function(now, fx) {
                    //this is never called, don't know why
                    alert(now);
                }
            }, function(){
                /*
                    Should I do the following?
                    orig_scrollDepth = $(document).scrollTop();*/
            });

            /*Without the next line, the bubble slides down from the top of the 
            tube on any length scroll in any direction*/
            orig_scrollDepth = $(document).scrollTop();
     }
}
```

---

#### Edit:

Wow, I just checked with a Samsung Galaxy S1 (standard web browser). The z-indexing and absolute positioning of the measuring tape are disastrously failing. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your use of `.css` is making it jumpy? `.animate` could be a suitable replacement, with a very fast setting so that it smoothly glides to the temporary starting position, then slowly glides back to the center afterward.

```
$('#bubble').animate({'top': (temp<-50?-50:(temp>50?50:temp)) +'%'},{duration:200})
    .animate( [...]
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks. Do you have a reason why you choose a fixed value of 200? Alternatives might include a factor of the top value to be set (`4 * Math.abs(what-the-top-value-is-being-set-to)`, i.e. 0-200) and a factor of the distance to be travelled (i.e. difference between current and destination: `(Math.abs(what-the-top-value-is-being-set-to- current-top-value)+50)/0.5`)

Comment: I figured it was the type of thing you'd need to play around with until you like the results anyway, so the number didn't matter to me at the time of posting.

Comment: Cool. You're right; I just did some testing and the first alternative makes it jumpy again. I might have to have a look at what a real spirit level does because for example, if you scroll up and down a lot then it sets off a long chain of animations after you stop (not that I should even worry about someone doing that but still) :)